# Getting product and seller info from eBay using APIs and Python

Tags: python-2.7, ebay-api

My question is about building and requesting a URL from a server using Python. Here specifically the eBay APIs. I want to submit the request and get the response and process the received Json in Python. I tried using the eBay Python sdk but I don't know how to use it for a price comparison sort of thing, or to get the seller information and anything else. I was able to use the finding API and get a category of products and I was able to iterate over products and get details.

I guess I could make URLs according to eBay API doc, if you can give me some examples of how it's done. I am really interested in using the new APIs, the analytics and metadata.

[ebay Api Documentation](https://go.developer.ebay.com/api-documentation)

Comment: This is rather vague, and is too broad for Stack Overflow. We don't know how your price comparison site should work. As far as I know eBay offers a way to get lists of items and their prices. I expect it would be your job to read a series of items in for a product category, and then work out what items are comparable, and put the prices into your comparison database. In general, list operations in REST are paginated, so you will probably need to do several HTTP operations for a category, leaving a delay between each.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I found the requests library and thats what I wanted,I asked how could i create that get calls to the api other than just creating the url by hand and requests do just that.